# Allow Case insensitive in Char form in Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I have an model where i have an foreign key and char field,

i want them to be save in unique together but Case insensitive over char field

example
(1, central) and (1, Central) both should be allowed to save

If (1, central) is saved and when I am adding (1, Central) I am getting below error

**error Tags with this Rooms and Aws room_name already exists.**

**Django1.8 -> MODEL.py**

```
class Tags():
Rooms = models.ForeignKey(Rooms, related_name='rooms')
room_name = models.CharField(
    verbose_name=_('room_name'),
    max_length=100,
    null=False,
    blank=False,
    default="",
)

class Meta:
    unique_together = (('Rooms', 'room_name'))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make a `UniqueConstraint` that works with the lowercase of a name:

```
class Tags(models.Model):
    room = models.ForeignKey(Rooms, related_name='rooms')
    room_name = models.CharField(
        verbose_name=_('room_name'),
        max_length=100,
        null=False,
        blank=False,
        default='',
    )

    class Meta:
        constraints = [
            models.UniqueConstrant(
                Lower('room_name'), 'room', name='unique_room_name_per_name'
            )
        ]
```

Converting the string to lowercase is in some cultures however not case-invariant. Indeed, some languages have sophisticated rules regarding when two strings are considered the same, and some characters have no lowercase/uppercase equivalent.

---

> **Note**: normally a Django model is given a *singular* name, so `Room` instead of <s>`Rooms`</s>.

---

> **Note**: normally the name of the fields in a Django model are written in *snake_case*, not *PascalCase*, so it should be: `room` instead of <s>`Room`</s>.

---

> **Note**: As the [documentation on **`unique_together`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/options/#unique-together) says, the `unique_together` constraint will likely become deprecated. The documentation advises to use the [**`UniqueConstraint`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/constraints/#django.db.models.UniqueConstraint) from Django's [*constraint
> framework*](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/constraints/#django.db.models.UniqueConstraint).

Comment: I am using django1.8 so Constraint is not available as its for >2

Comment: @Vaibhav: yes, in that case you should definitely upgrade, Django-1.8 is no longer supported, since **april 2018**. Meanwhile a *lot* of security issues have been discovered. But Django indeed did not supported most "advanced" SQL  features before Django-2.0.

Comment: Upgrade is not possible because of legacy system

Comment: @Vaibhav: an upgrade is definitely possible. Django actually has quite some good documentation what went deprecated, etc. But it will of course take time, but looks better than waiting for someone to exploit vulnerabilities. https://security.snyk.io/package/pip/django https://security.snyk.io/package/pip/django/1.8